# Why it don't generate R.id.**** automatically?

Tags: android, eclipse

I write `android:id="@+id/TextAccount"` ,but it did not generate an id in **`R.java`** automatically.So I can't launch it to my phone,there are always errors.So how can I do to solve this problem?  I am new here . Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you Clean And Build Automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason the R.class can go missing suddenly is when there are errors in you xml files. For instance when you add an xml file with uppercase letters in the name like myCoolLayout.xml which is not allowed. Or when you have references that don't point to existing files etc.

Try this:

1. Delete any import to an R.java class.
2. Move your cursor to a reference to any
   button/layout/string/whatever-coming-from-R, delete the last
   character, and hit ctrl+space. Eclipse will try to codehint you,
   automatically importing the correct R.java.
3. Just to keep it cool, clean and rebuild.

Comment: Happy to help :) Accept my answer if it helps for you @vankee

Answer (score 0):

That happens when there is some error in your project which will not allow to update R.java. Check your error and then rebuild project. It will sort out.